# Emailing automatically

Tags: infopath, email, submit

I have created a form in InfoPath 2010 with a submit button and deployed the form to SharePoint. The form opens from SharePoint in browser.  For a long time the users would click on the form, fill it out, click submit and the form would automatically email to me; however, now when they click 'submit' the email message box comes up where the user could change the email address to which the form is being emailed. How do I have the email send automatically so they cannot see to whom the form is submitted?

Comment: How was the email previously being sent? Is there a workflow that sends an email when I new item is created? Or is there an action/rule in InfoPath that sends an email?